# Android Picasso transformation not applied on each view show

Tags: android, transformation, picasso

I'm using Picasso :

```
Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(url)
                .placeholder(fallback)
                .error(fallback)
                .transform(new CircleTransform(userStatus))
                .into(this);
```

And Transformation to apply stroke and roundness to the image:

```
public class CircleTransform implements Transformation {
        private int userStatus = UserProfile.STATUS_TYPE_NONE;

        public CircleTransform(int userStatus) {
            this.userStatus = userStatus;
        }

        @Override
        public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
            int size = Math.min(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight());

            int x = (source.getWidth() - size) / 2;
            int y = (source.getHeight() - size) / 2;

            Bitmap squaredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, x, y, size, size);
            if (squaredBitmap != source) {
                source.recycle();
            }

            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(size, size, source.getConfig());

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(squaredBitmap, BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP, BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP);
            paint.setShader(shader);
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);

            float r = size / 2f;
            canvas.drawCircle(r, r, r, paint);
            if (UserProfile.STATUS_TYPE_NONE != userStatus) {
                Paint paintStroke = new Paint();
                paintStroke.setAntiAlias(true);
                if (UserProfile.STATUS_TYPE_BRONZE == userStatus)
                    paintStroke.setColor(Colors.bronzeColor);
                else if (UserProfile.STATUS_TYPE_SILVER == userStatus)
                    paintStroke.setColor(Colors.silverColor);
                else if (UserProfile.STATUS_TYPE_GOLD == userStatus)
                    paintStroke.setColor(Colors.goldColor);
                else if (UserProfile.STATUS_TYPE_PLATINUM == userStatus)
                    paintStroke.setColor(Colors.platinumColor);
                else if (UserProfile.STATUS_TYPE_DIAMOND == userStatus)
                    paintStroke.setColor(Colors.diamondColor);

                paintStroke.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
                float stroke = size * CIRCLE_SIZE_IN_PERCENT;
                paintStroke.setStrokeWidth(stroke);
                canvas.drawCircle(r, r, r - (stroke / 2), paintStroke);
            }
            squaredBitmap.recycle();
            return bitmap;
        }

        @Override
        public String key() {
            return "circle";
        }
    }
```

the problem is that the public `Bitmap transform(Bitmap source)` is not getting called each time the image is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

The `userStatus` variable changes the behavior of the transformation and thus must be included in the cache key. Otherwise Picasso thinks that any circle transformation can be replaced with another.

```
@Override
public String key() {
    return "circle" + userStatus;
}
```

Comment: This is not working, if I Use userStatus, then I don see the transformation applied. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Ok I found the solution, the transformation key stays the same and it dose not apply a new one with the same key, so I changed

```
 @Override
        public String key() {
            return "circle";
        }
```

to:

```
@Override
        public String key() {
            return "circle" + value;
        }
```

value - should be unique parameter defining the instance of the ImageView. I hope it helps someone :)

Comment: This eliminates all memory caching.